# Check if date is inside range in pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following 2 dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c': ['abc', 'def', 'wyx', 'abc', 'wyx'], 'begin_date': ['2020-01-01', '2000-12-23', '2003-07-07', '2005-03-02', '2009-02-01'], 'end_date': ['2020-01-31', '2001-02-02', '2004-03-02', '2005-04-01', '2010-07-04']})

c  begin_date    end_date
abc  2020-01-01  2020-01-31
def  2000-12-23  2001-02-02
wyx  2003-07-07  2004-03-02
abc  2005-03-02  2005-04-01
wyx  2009-02-01  2010-07-04
```

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.arange(5), 'c': ['wyx', 'abc', 'abc', 'def', 'qwe'], 'date': ['2003-12-12', '2020-02-02', '2005-03-15', '2002-11-05', '2005-01-01']})

id    c        date
0  wyx  2003-12-12
1  abc  2020-02-02
2  abc  2005-03-15
3  def  2002-11-05
4  qwe  2005-01-01
```

And I want to find which ids in `df1` have a date inside a range in `df` based on c.

My final dataframe would be this:

```
id    c        date  in_range
0  wyx  2003-12-12      True
1  abc  2020-02-02     False
2  abc  2005-03-15      True
3  def  2002-11-05     False
```

I managed to do it with this code:

```
x = df1.merge(df, on='c')
x['in_range'] = x['date'].ge(x['begin_date'])&x['date'].le(x['end_date'])
x.groupby(['id', 'c', 'date'])['in_range'].sum().reset_index()
```

But I think there might be a easier way and I also have more columns in `df1` which would make the groupby very large.

Comment: I think it is ok to use merge ~ here